# Underlining text with repeated symbol

Tags: tikz-pgf, underline

I'd like to underline by repeating a symbol (for example `+`). I have this code that works for underlining with `x` but I couldn't make it work for `+`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.shapes}

\newcommand{\latexunderplus}[1]{%
    \tikz[baseline=(todotted.base)]{
        \node[inner xsep=0pt,inner ysep=1pt,outer sep=0pt] (todotted) {#1};
        \draw[decorate,decoration={crosses,shape size=1pt},segment length=2pt] (todotted.south west) -- (todotted.south east);
    }%
}%

\begin{document}
\latexunderplus{qwe}
\end{document}
```

From what I've read, I could probably use `\pgfdeclareshape` to declare a new shape corresponding to my symbol, and then use it instead of `crosses`. This would imply telling tikz how to draw each symbol that I use for underlining. Is there another (simpler) way? For example some function that automagically turns a character into a shape?

Comment: Can you make the example compilable, with the successful `x` try and the unsuccessful `+` try?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are willing to try a bit of plain TeX you can do this with boxes and leaders:

```
\documentclass{article}
\def\undermark#1#2{\setbox0\hbox{#2}\hbox to 0pt{\copy0\hss}\lower2ex\hbox to
   \wd0{\cleaders\hbox{#1}\hfil}}
\begin{document}
However, a service-oriented \undermark{$\cdot$}{paradigm} is further compounded
when taking into account the evolution of specifications over a given time period.
Interestingly enough, the fully integrated test program presents extremely
interesting challenges to the preliminary \undermark{$\scriptstyle+$}{qualification} limit.  Similarly, the
incorporation of additional mission constraints must utilize and be functionally
interwoven with possible bidirectional logical relationship \undermark{x}{approaches}.
\end{document}
```

[image]

### Observations

- This is not very robust - for example it will mess with the line breaking if you use it near the end of a line.
- I think it looks ugly typographically.

### Explanation

- `\def\undermark#1#2` defines a command that expects two arguments
- `\setbox0\hbox{#2}` sets box register 0 to a box containing the second arg
- `\hbox to 0pt{\copy0\hss}` typesets a box of zero width containing the contents of box register 0 with all the contents sticking out the right.
- `\lower2ex` typesets the following box 2ex below the baseline
- `\hbox to \wd0{}` typesets a a box stretched to the width of box register 0
- `\cleaders\hbox{#1}\hfil` creates a stretchy pattern made with copies of box containing the first argument

Comment: Using this with the `anyfontsize` works pretty well, except that I have to manually replace the `2ex` with whatever works (which won't be the same for `abc` and `qwe` because of the `q`).

Comment: And about typographical ugliness, it's the best I could find. I have things (terms) that are either positive or negative, and I want to annotate them. The problem is that the supscript is already taken (by ' among other things), and so when I have several of them (for example $t_1$ and $t_2$), making explicit that they are positive with indices makes it ugly ($t_{1+}$, ${t_{1}}_+$, $(t_1)_+$) so instead, I thought of underlining with plus signs $\latexunderplus{t_1}$. I think it makes it decently readable.

Comment: I picked 2ex because that would clear the descenders in most cases, but you could parameterize it with, say, `\ht0`...

Comment: I tried to make it work with `\dimexpr` and `\ht0` but apparently `\ht` gives the same height to `a` and `q` (which is good for normal underline, but makes it look weird when the underline is made of `+`s).

Comment: there is also `\dp0`, the depth below the baseline...

Comment: It works perfectly with `\the\dimexpr\dp0+2pt\relax` instead of `2ex` and `\fontsize{2pt}{3pt}\selectfont` in front of the `+`. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

You may just rotate the crosses and invent a new decoration for the `\ominus`. This can be done by looking up `pgflibrarydecorations.shapes.code.tex`, copying the code from there and adjusting it.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.shapes}

\makeatletter
\pgfdeclaredecoration{ominus}{init}
{
  \state{init}[width=+0pt,next state=crosses,persistent precomputation={
    \pgfmathparse{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/decoration/shape start width}/sqrt(8)}
    \edef\pgf@lib@dec@ssw{\pgfmathresult pt}
    \pgfmathparse{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/decoration/shape start height}/2}
    \edef\pgf@lib@dec@ssh{\pgfmathresult pt}
  }]{}  
  \state{crosses}[switch if less than=+\pgfdecorationsegmentlength to last,
                  width=+\pgfdecorationsegmentlength]
  {
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{-\pgf@lib@dec@ssw}{0pt}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{\pgf@lib@dec@ssw}{0pt}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{\pgf@lib@dec@ssw}{0pt}}
    \pgfpathcircle{\pgfpointorigin}{\pgf@lib@dec@ssw}\pgfusepath{stroke}
  }
  \state{last}[width=+\pgfdecoratedremainingdistance]
  {
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{-\pgf@lib@dec@ssw}{0pt}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{\pgf@lib@dec@ssw}{0pt}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{\pgf@lib@dec@ssw}{0pt}}
    \pgfpathcircle{\pgfpointorigin}{\pgf@lib@dec@ssw}\pgfusepath{stroke}
  }
  \state{final}{
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpointdecoratedpathlast}
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{-\pgf@lib@dec@ssw}{0pt}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{\pgf@lib@dec@ssw}{0pt}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{\pgf@lib@dec@ssw}{0pt}}
    \pgfpathcircle{\pgfpointorigin}{\pgf@lib@dec@ssw}\pgfusepath{stroke}
  }
}
\makeatother


\newcommand{\latexunderplus}[1]{%
    \tikz[baseline=(todotted.base)]{
        \node[inner xsep=0pt,inner ysep=1pt,outer sep=0pt] (todotted) {#1};
        \draw[decorate,decoration={crosses,shape size=2pt,transform={rotate=45}},segment length=2pt] (todotted.south west) -- (todotted.south east);
    }%
}%

\newcommand{\latexunderominus}[1]{%
    \tikz[baseline=(todotted.base)]{
        \node[inner xsep=0pt,inner ysep=1pt,outer sep=0pt] (todotted) {#1};
        \draw[decorate,decoration={ominus,shape size=5pt},segment length=5pt] (todotted.south west) -- (todotted.south east);
    }%
}%



\begin{document}
\latexunderplus{qwe}
\latexunderominus{qwe}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, but I also need it for $\ominus$. I should've taken another symbol as example...

Comment: @xavierm02 OK, now with ominus. Please have a look at my update.

Answer (score 0):

The two solutions side by side:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.shapes}
\usepackage{anyfontsize}
\usepackage{calc}
\def\undermark#1#2{
    \setbox0\hbox{#2}\hbox to 0pt{\copy0\hss}\lower\the\dimexpr\dp0+2pt\relax\hbox to
    \wd0{\cleaders\hbox{#1}\hfil}}

\makeatletter
\pgfdeclaredecoration{ominus}{init}
{
    \state{init}[width=+0pt,next state=crosses,persistent precomputation={
        \pgfmathparse{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/decoration/shape start width}/sqrt(8)}
        \edef\pgf@lib@dec@ssw{\pgfmathresult pt}
        \pgfmathparse{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/decoration/shape start height}/2}
        \edef\pgf@lib@dec@ssh{\pgfmathresult pt}
    }]{}  
    \state{crosses}[switch if less than=+\pgfdecorationsegmentlength to last,
    width=+\pgfdecorationsegmentlength]
    {
        \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{-\pgf@lib@dec@ssw}{0pt}}
        \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{\pgf@lib@dec@ssw}{0pt}}
        \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{\pgf@lib@dec@ssw}{0pt}}
        \pgfpathcircle{\pgfpointorigin}{\pgf@lib@dec@ssw}\pgfusepath{stroke}
    }
    \state{last}[width=+\pgfdecoratedremainingdistance]
    {
        \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{-\pgf@lib@dec@ssw}{0pt}}
        \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{\pgf@lib@dec@ssw}{0pt}}
        \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{\pgf@lib@dec@ssw}{0pt}}
        \pgfpathcircle{\pgfpointorigin}{\pgf@lib@dec@ssw}\pgfusepath{stroke}
    }
    \state{final}{
        \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpointdecoratedpathlast}
        \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{-\pgf@lib@dec@ssw}{0pt}}
        \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{\pgf@lib@dec@ssw}{0pt}}
        \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{\pgf@lib@dec@ssw}{0pt}}
        \pgfpathcircle{\pgfpointorigin}{\pgf@lib@dec@ssw}\pgfusepath{stroke}
    }
}
\makeatother

\newcommand{\latexunderplus}[1]{%
    \tikz[baseline=(todotted.base)]{
        \node[inner xsep=0pt,inner ysep=1pt,outer sep=0pt] (todotted) {#1};
        \draw[decorate,decoration={crosses,shape size=1.5pt,transform={rotate=45}},segment length=2.5pt] (todotted.south west) -- (todotted.south east);
    }%
}%

\newcommand{\latexunderominus}[1]{%
    \tikz[baseline=(todotted.base)]{
        \node[inner xsep=0pt,inner ysep=1pt,outer sep=0pt] (todotted) {#1};
        \draw[decorate,decoration={ominus,shape size=2.5pt},segment length=3pt] (todotted.south west) -- (todotted.south east);
    }%
}%

\begin{document}

\newcommand{\mytest}[1]{
    $\latexunderplus{\ensuremath{#1}}$
    $\latexunderominus{\ensuremath{#1}}$
    vs
    $\undermark{\fontsize{2pt}{3pt}\selectfont +}{\ensuremath{#1}}$
    $\undermark{\fontsize{2pt}{3pt}\selectfont \ensuremath{\ominus}}{\ensuremath{#1}}$
}

\mytest{\ensuremath{V_1}}\\
\mytest{qwe}\\
\mytest{abc}


\end{document}
```